# Como modificar CSS inline após carregamento da página?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5, css3

Boas,

Estou fazendo uma consulta à base de dados, onde existe um campo que possui conteúdo em html. Dentro desse conteúdo existe uma table, que possui algum CSS aplicado inline com uma width definida em px.

Preciso de alterar a propriedade width da tabela para 100%;
O problema é que estou a mostrar esse código por php uma vez que este vem da base de dados.

Ou seja, na realidade o que esotu a fazer é apenas isto:

```
echo $dados;
```

Todo o código html está dentro de $dados. 
Tentei explicar de forma mais clara...

Agradeço a ajuda.

Cumps.

Comment: Você pode usar jQuery se a tabela tiver algum tipo de classe que você possa pegar

Comment: Você dispara esse "evento" como ? a lógica está no PHP ?

Comment: @KhaosDoctor a tabela não tem nenhuma class associada nem nenhum id e não consigo atribuir nenhum.

Comment: `$('table').css('width', '100%');` ?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro o PHP está a ser usado apenas para mostrar os dados da bd.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira lembrei disso.. mas isso vai alterar em todas as tabelas existentes na página certo ?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida sim. Se a tabela que você quer for a primeira, pode fazer `$('table:first-of-type')`

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira hummm... vou tentar fazer assim.. se for a terceira posso fazer $('table:third-of-type') ????????

Comment: A sua tabela provavelmente será impressa dentro de algum elemento que você tem uma identificação certo ? pesquise uma tabela dentro desse elemento em particular: `$( "#minhaDiv" ).find( "table" ).css( "width", "100%" );
`

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro boa dica... acho que peguei a solução... obrigado.

Comment: @LuísAlmeida se for a terceira, o seletor é `$('table:nth-child(3)')`

Comment: O ideal seria que você editasse a sua pergunta e colocasse o HTML gerado pra que a gente tenha uma ideia melhor de como te ajudar

Comment: Com vossas resposta eu já consegui modificar a width da table. :)
não coloquei o html, porque é muito grande mesmo. Mas já cheguei à solução.
Obrigado.

Comment: @LuísAlmeida vou postar minha sugestão como resposta, se ela resolveu seu problema, aceite como resposta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso sua tabela seja impressa dentro de um outro elemento que você tenha identificado, pode utilizar o método `find()` do [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para buscar somente neste elemento.

Exemplo:

```
$( "#minhaDiv" ).find( "table" ).css( "width", "100%" );
```